# CGridView pagination format

Tags: yii, pagination, cgridview

i like to get the pagination in the CGridView in this format

- normal structure: **<< < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 > >>**
- require structure: **<< < 4 5 6 > >>**

is there any solution for this. please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Simple changing CLinkPager

in your config should be a strings:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.components.*',
),
```

### Create a file ./protected/components/LinkPager.php

```
<?php 
class LinkPager extends CLinkPager {
    public $maxButtonCount=3;
}
```

### Then when you use CGridView in your code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'pager'=>'LinkPager',
));
```

By steps above, you creating a new pager class, which is used by CGridView for rendering pager section.

Comment: hello @rusalex. can you provide me any example of this. i am poor in yii.

Comment: Note that if you didn't want to make this global, you could also set the maxButtonCount attribute when you define your widget.

Comment: @idg how would u do that?

Comment: @RusAlex i tried this with `zii.widgets.CListView` but it didn't work. any ideas?